# How to print n numbers per line

Tags: java

Hello I have an issue where I have to print out the numbers divisible by 17
but I want to print out 5 numbers and then jump down to the next line.
This is the code that I have and don't know why it's not working....

```
public class seventeen {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int num = 17;
      System.out.print("The Numbers Divisible By 17 are: ");
      int enter = 0;
      for (int x = 1; x <= 10000; x++) {
         if (x % num == 0) {
            System.out.print(x + " ");
         }
         enter++;
         if (enter == 5) {
            enter = 0;
            System.out.println();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you run this code?

Comment: @SamIam every 5 numbers will print a line break.

Comment: Still you got the answer :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza finding the answer wasn't completely the point.  I was trying to get the OP to say something other than "it doesn't work"

Comment: @SamIam I know, that's why I posted an answer in CW state.

Answer (score 6):

You should only increment your counter when the number validation is reached. This means, move the `enter++;` inside the validation:

```
if (x % num == 0) {
    System.out.print(x + " ");
    enter++;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to make this one CW?

Comment: Yes, I think that this kind of answer shouldn't give me any rep.

Comment: Wow thank you I'm sorry.
The semester just started and I'm a little rusty..
Thanks!

Comment: @DavidCamacho you're welcome. Next time you have a problem, use a debugger to see why the code behaves *strange*.

Comment: But the debugger didn't give me anything... it ran completely fine just with a lot of line breaks, I just wasn't thinking logically

Comment: @DavidCamacho using the degubber would have shown you that the `enter` variable increments on each iteration. Then you have wondered *why does my code behave like this?* and probably get to the conclusion the counter should be inside the validation.

Comment: Now, I know this is WAY off topic, but my teacher didn't provide us with a book for data structure (this is my 3rd programming course) and we just have a simple online ebook. Which one do you recommend? The course is called COSC Data Structure in Java

Comment: @DavidCamacho hover the mouse over the `[java]` tag and select the [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) where you will access to StackOverflow's Java wiki. There are plenty online resources there from basic to intermediate-advanced topics to learn.

Comment: I'd move the `if (enter == 5) { ... }` inside `if (x%num==0)` also.  No point in testing it in every iteration; it only matters on the ones where you actually print something.  Also, at the end of the program, make sure you don't leave in the middle of the line: `if (enter > 0) System.out.println();`

Answer (score 0):

changing your loop to 
`for(int x = 17 ; x <= 10000 ; x+=17)`
should solve it, and make your code about 17x faster.

Then you can remove your modulus check as well.

Answer (score 0):

As others have posted, incrementing `enter` should be done only when you actually print something; and there's no point in testing it for 5 in the loop iterations when you don't print something.

Another point is to make sure you finish correctly.  If the last line has 5 numbers, then `enter` will be 0 after the loop is done, and you'll be on the next line.  But if the last line is short, you want to make sure to do a `println()` after you're done.  So:

```
  int enter = 0;
  for (int x = 1; x <= 10000; x++) {
     if (x % num == 0) {
        System.out.print(x + " ");
        enter++;
        if (enter == 5) {
           enter = 0;
           System.out.println();
        }
     }
  }
  if (enter > 0)
     System.out.println();
```

(P.S. I'd actually use the `x+=17` method in other answers, but this idiom could come up in many other cases where you actually do have to look at every item and only print some of them.)